# VBA Stuck at Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a request form where the inputs from the form will transfer to a separate excel sheet

I have this code but error 91 keeps on showing, what went wrong?

```
Dim book2 As Workbook

book2 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Requests\Request Form.xlsm")

emptyrow = book2.Sheets("Logs").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row+1

book2.Sheets("Logs").Range("A" & emptyrow).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Request Form").Range("J9:K9").Value

book2.Sheets("Logs").Range("B" & emptyrow).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Request Form").Range("J12:K9").Value

book2.Sheets("Logs").Range("C" & emptyrow).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Request Form").Range("C12").Value
```

Comment: Which line returns the error?

Comment: Set Book2=.  Also, where is books defined?

Comment: Line 3 returns the error, the code wont proceed after the book2 opens

Comment: Hi dave, apologies for the typo, i was using my phone as the site is not accessible on my computer. books.sheets is book2.sheets on my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

book2 is a Workbook Object. Objects need to be Set. Change line 2 to:

```
Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Requests\Request Form.xlsm")
```